# Calculate check digit for UPC-A barcode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, check-digit

I'm currently working on a windows form in VS2010 that is supposed to create UPC-A for new part numbers and store them in a database. So far I'm still trying to get the pieces together and I'm having issues with calculating the check digit. I came up with the following two scenarios:

Scenario 1: Do the calculation the way we currently do it in Excel:

```
string value = uPCDataSet.UPC.Rows[uPCDataSet.UPC.Rows.Count - 1]["UPCNumber"].ToString();
string manCode = value.Substring(1, 5);
string prodCode = value.Substring(7, 5);
int first = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(value));

while (first >= 10)
first /= 10;

int chkDigitSubtotal;

string UPCNumber = first + manCode + prodCode;

chkDigitSubtotal = Convert.ToInt32((UPCNumber.Substring(1, 1)) + (UPCNumber.Substring(3, 1)) + 
(UPCNumber.Substring(5, 1)) + (UPCNumber.Substring(7, 1)) + (UPCNumber.Substring(9, 1)) + 
(UPCNumber.Substring(11, 1)));

chkDigitSubtotal = (3 * chkDigitSubtotal) + Convert.ToInt32((UPCNumber.Substring(2, 1)) + 
(UPCNumber.Substring(4, 1)) + (UPCNumber.Substring(6, 1)) + (UPCNumber.Substring(8, 1)) + 
(UPCNumber.Substring(10, 1)));

 string chkDigit = ((300 - chkDigitSubtotal).ToString()).Substring(12, 1);
```

When I run this code, I get an error "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32". I don't understand why since "value" is a `varchar` with 12 characters (they are all numbers).

Scenario 2: I found a code snipped online. This code works, but gives me the wrong check digit. I'm using a UPC that we calculated using your Excel sheet:

```
string value = "606891001678"; //valid UPC with check digit
string UPCBody = value.Substring(0, 11);
int sum = 0;
bool odd = true;

for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (odd == true)
    {
        int tSum = Convert.ToInt32(value[i].ToString()) * 2;

        if (tSum >= 10)
        {
            string tData = tSum.ToString();
            tSum = Convert.ToInt32(tData[0].ToString()) + Convert.ToInt32(tData[1].ToString());
        }
        sum += tSum;
    }
    else
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(value[i].ToString());

    odd = !odd;
}

int result = (((sum / 10)+1) *10) - sum;
result = result % 10;
MessageBox.Show(UPCBody + " & " + result);
```

In this example the check digit obviously should be 8, but it returns 2.
I've spent pretty much all day on this and could use some advice. Why am I getting the error on the first scenario and why am I getting a different check digit in the second scenario from what it should be?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Chris

EDIT:

I deleted two previous edits since the code was flawed in a sense that I didn't get the correct results. I found out that we use Azalea barcodes and they have their own method of calculating the check digit (see ChkDigitSubtotal).
So the below code works and gives me the correct check digit for my scenario. I think this code will work up to chkDigitSubtotal for all UPC-A calculations. Thanks to Harrison for his great guidance and resourceful answer!

```
string value = uPCDataSet.UPC.Rows[uPCDataSet.UPC.Rows.Count - 1]
["UPCNumber"].ToString();
long chkDigitOdd;
long chkDigitEven;
long chkDigitSubtotal;
string UPCNumber = value.Substring(0, 11);
chkDigitOdd = Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(0, 1)) +
Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(2, 1)) + Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(4, 1)) 
+ Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(6, 1)) + Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(8, 
1)) + Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(10, 1));
chkDigitOdd = (3 * chkDigitOdd);
chkDigitEven = Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(1, 1)) + 
Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(3, 1)) + Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(5, 1)) 
+ Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(7, 1)) + Convert.ToInt64(UPCNumber.Substring(9, 
1));
chkDigitSubtotal = (300-(chkDigitEven + chkDigitOdd));
string chkDigit = chkDigitSubtotal.ToString();
chkDigit = chkDigit.Substring(chkDigit.Length - 1, 1);
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem, but C# doesn't have a type called "varchar". That sounds like a type in a database. Int32 can handle numbers from -2147483648 to +2147483647, which, while it's a 10 digit number, does not support the full range you'll need. Add in the check digit and you'll need 11 digits. Try using the `Decimal` type, which supports something like 28 digits.

Comment: @Steve, varchar is indeed the field type in the SQL database where "value" comes from. I will look into Decimal and see if it gets me anywhere. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Once you load the value from the database into your .NET program, you're working with .NET CLR types. By the way, here is a list of value types in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: In your calculation for `chkDigitSubtotal` (in the first example) you add 6 1 digit strings and convert it to a number.  The most that could be is 999,999.  Then you multiply by 3 = 2,999,997 and add again a 5 digit string maxing out at 99,999 = 3099996 max.  Now you take this and subtract it from 300 = -3,099,696.  I see 8 characters including the minus sign (not including commas).  I'm not sure how you would take the 12th character of a string that is 8 characters long? Did I make a mistake in the calculation?

Comment: This code works BEAUTIFULLY!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I'm reading on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#UPC) your doing the calculation incorrectly in the first example.

- `String.Substring` + `String.Subtring` or "1" + "1" = "11".  You are
  looking for 1+1=2.  You need to convert each substring to int prior
  to adding.

[+ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx)

> Binary + operators are predefined for numeric and string types. For
>   numeric types, + computes the sum of its two operands. *When one or
>   both operands are of type string, + concatenates the string
>   representations of the operands.*

- `String.Substring` is 0 based so you are missing the
  `String.Substring(0,1)` for your even digits

[String.Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

> startIndex: The zero-based starting character position of a substring
>   in this instance.

- Your checkdigit string attempts to take the 12th digit of a string which is less than 12 digits.  Also, this isn't the calculation as seen in the link.  It's looking for 10 - mod 10 of that number.  This is also happening in your *updated edit* in the line

`string chkDigit = ((300 - chkDigitSubtotal).ToString()).Substring(12, 1);`

You are attempting to take a `Substring` from the 12th 0 based character, or 13th character for a length of 1.  However, the value of chkDigitSubtotal will not be that large/long.

As far as your error, As Golden Dragon states in his answer your are converting a 12 characcter string to a number, which won't fit into an `Int32` and you should use a long.

```
int first = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(value));
```

goes to

```
long first = Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt64(value));
```

I would check your calculation is actually functioning logically in the previous steps first.

**Update**

In your *edit 2* it looks like your last line has the variables around the [`% operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0w4e0fzs.aspx) reversed.  You want to take the remainder of 109 divided by 10 (which is 9) and your code takes the remainder of 10 divided by 109 (which is 0)  So change.

```
chkDigitSubtotal = 10 - (10 % (chkDigitEven + chkDigitOdd));
```

to

```
chkDigitSubtotal = 10 - ((chkDigitEven + chkDigitOdd) % 10);
```

Now 10 - 9 = 1 which is your checkDigit.

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thanks for the detailed answer and I think I got a much better idea of what to do. I updated the code but now get a much different error. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I added a line to the answer to show you why the error is there.

Comment: Got it figured out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I really appreciate that you didn't just give me code but pointed out my flaws and gave me resources for research. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is a 12 digit long string, then it is much too large to fit into an `int`.  Use a `long` instead